SystemVerilog - N access controlled devices, all unique by default, need parameter mechanism for allowing them to be grouped
I'd like a parameter like this:
parameter bit GROUP [N - 1:0] = '{0:0, 1:1, 2:2, 3:3, etc...}

So each index is in its own group but in a way that an integrator can integrate the module and also override this to group some of the instances together (like 0 and 1), eg
.GROUP ('{0:0, 1:0, 2:2, 3:3, etc...})

But this is very difficult to do with a parameter of N for number of devices especially when that number can be 30 or more.
I was hoping for something like:
.GROUP = '{default: self.idx}

So that an integrator could do this:
.GROUP ('{default: self.idx, 1:0})

Is there some better way of doing this?

Parameter values can be set using a constant function. These function are restricted to the rules defined in section 13.4.3 Constant functions in the IEEE 1800-2023 SystemVerilog LRM.
module device;
  parameter int N=1;
  typedef int array_t[N]; // note functions returing unpacked arrays need typedef
  parameter array_t GROUP = series();

  function array_t series;
    foreach(series[i]) series[i] = i;
  endfunction
  initial $display("%m GROUP %p",GROUP);
endmodule

module top;
  parameter int Ntop=10;
  typedef int array_t[Ntop];
  function array_t seriesOverride(int idx);
    foreach(seriesOverride[i]) seriesOverride[i] = i;
    seriesOverride[idx] = 0;
  endfunction
  
  
  device #( .N(5) ) d5();
  device #( .N(Ntop), .GROUP(seriesOverride(4)) ) d10();
  
endmodule

